# Redirect if homepage

Tags: module, magento-1, 301-redirect

Im trying to make the Homepage invisible since im doing an integration between 2 sites and the non Magento site handles the Homepage already. So far I achieved this temporally with a JS redirect but this is a bad idea.

Is there any way to do a 301 redirect from the Homepage to another URL? For the record, the destination URL it's outside Magento.

Comment: Yep, from the admin Dashboard->Catalog->URL Rewrite Management

Comment: @Samuel- I'd agree with you and you should probably put that in as an answer.

Comment: I should have done that from the beginning. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have it easier than a rewrite! Just set the homepage to a url you want.

```
System > Config > General > Web > Default Pages > Default Web Url
```

There you can fill in whatever you want, e.g.

- a category: `catalog/category/view/id/7`
- or a product page: `catalog/product/view/id/7`
- or a cms page

This is only an internal redirect and the customer doesn't see that it is a category (that can be a downside)

Answer (score 1):

Magento provides URL rewriting, including 301 redirects.

Rewrites can be found in the admin dashboard->Catalog->URL Rewrite Management

Some more info can be found here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-url-rewrites (even if the tutorial is for Magento Go, it's the same on Community)